# UITableViewController: Swipe to delete enabled if condition is satisfied

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitableview, swipe

For UIViewController reuse purpose I want to allow the "Swipe to Delete" gesture only in case that a condition is satisfied. Is there a way to achieve that?

If I add the following UITableViewController Delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

the "Swipe to delete" is enabled but I'm not able to discriminate in which cases I want to disable this gesture

Comment: Take a look in the UITableViewDelegate and the method: - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
        editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL someCondition = // figure out whether you want swipe to be available
    return (someCondition) ?
        UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete : UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Comes from the end of this section of my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_deleting_table_items

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete==YES)
    {
          // here goes your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your logic inside of the delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
    editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

## For Example

To only allow editing on the odd rows:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
        editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    else return UITableViewEditingStyleNone;
}
```

### Percent Sign?!

This is something I love teaching just because it can be so useful in so many circumstances - in the block of code `indexPath.row  2 == 1`, were checking to see if the row of the indexPath is odd. Here's how it works: The percent sign is called a modulus. What is does is it performs the division much like you would on a piece of paper, then takes the remainder of the calculation - once you understand this, you see how immensely powerful it would be. You can check to see if a number is divisible by another number, for example.

In our example, we're looking at what the remainder is when we divide the row by 2. If it's 0, we know its divisible by two, therefore it's even. If it returns 1, though, the row is odd. It's an amazing tool.